# sstream issue, CLION Mac

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using CLION in Mac OSX High Sierra, and when I compile, I have an error.

```
 cadena=static_cast<ostringstream*>(&(ostringstream()<<vidas))->str();
```

and the error is:

/Users/macbookpro-jonathanprieto/CLionProjects/xonixpacman/main.cpp:113:40: error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'std::__1::basic_ostringstream, std::__1::allocator >'
    cadena=static_cast(&(ostringstream()<str();

Comment: Well, you can't take the address of an rvalue. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I have never considered using a stringstream on the fly like that...

Breaking your statement down you have:

```
cadena
=
    static_cast<ostringstream*>
    (
        &(ostringstream()<<vidas)
    )->str();
```

ostringstream() will create a temporary, which you might be able to refer to as const std::ostream&, or as std::ostream&&, but not as an undecorated ostringstream.

It doesn't like you taking the pointer to that. I think you can static cast a reference?

So we fix those 2 issues and get to this, which compiles for me (don't know if it runs):

```
std::string cadena
=
    static_cast<const std::ostringstream&>
    (
        (std::ostringstream()<<std::string("vidas"))
    ).str();
```

Or

```
std::string cadena
=
    static_cast<std::ostringstream&&>
    (
        (std::ostringstream()<<std::string("vidas"))
    ).str();
```

Comment: You put vidas as a word but I need it as a variable !

Comment: Disaster! I didn't have a variable called vidas. :-) So change #std::string("vidas")# back to #vidas#